# RoboHelp is missing ouput preset for CHM generation

Tags: adobe, chm, preset, robohelp

Adobe RoboHelp 2020 Trial Version:

The list of available output presets is also missing Responsive HTML5, and Mobile App.

I did have a problem with the PDF output geneation. Error message advised to install Java runtime, as it was missing. After Java installation, PDF genearated. But its bookmarks did not work at all.

I have worked laboriously at learning how to use the RoboHelp; and also took several days to create my project. I desperately need to generate CHM output for a Windows program that I developed. I was devastated when I finally went to generate CHM output/Microsoft HTML Help, it was not on thelist of presets.

That said, I am at wits end, having searched for potential solutions. Can someone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Also the Adobe ***RoboHelp 2020 Trial Version*** contains the functionality to generate CHM help files.

To add and output the Microsoft HTML Help (CHM) in your presets, click the + icon in the Outputs panel as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Adobe RoboHelp 2020 Trial Version]

- Select Type  `Microsoft HTML Help`
- Enter a short Name like `CHM`

After that it is available for permanent use, e.g. in the `Quick Generate` window.

[image]

Comment: @trosoft - if this answer has helped you solve your problem (***"RoboHelp is missing ouput preset for CHM generation"***) feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up.

Answer (score 0):

I updated RH 2020.
I selected the Microsoft HTML Help preset
I configured the preset: I selected the TOC file. I specified the output folder, which is on a different drive than the project folder. (I knew that it could not be in the location whose parent folder was the project folder.)

Then I clicked the command button to generate the CHM. The progress display continuously indicated the various task that were being performed during the generation process.

Ultimately, I clicked the View Output button. The program displayed an error message indicating that the CHM filed could not be opened. I checked the output designation folder; and, the file existed. However, it was only 1 KB. I double-clicked the CHM file; but, the same error message appeared as when I attempted to open the file from within RoboHelp.

As an aside, I tried he same process with RoboHelp’s sample project, i.e., Compass Travel. And, wouldn’t you know it? The CHM file did properly generate and display; even the bookmarks functioned as expected.

---

That said, I had mentioned in the original post that I had generated a PDF output. But, the bookmarks did not worked.

Clarification:

The H 1 bookmarks display. However, clicking anyone of the them results in nothing. Whereas most of the H 1 folders have several H 2 subfolders; and there existed two H-3 level items.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post questions as answers. You can ask a new question and link to this one if it helps to provide context. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: If Windows can't open a CHM, RoboHelp certainly can't! Sorry, I hope you work under Windows?

Comment: ... and please note: The output folder for CHM's must be on a local drive and NOT on a network drive!